# Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute

Tags: python, kivy

пишу простой калькулятор с библиотекой KivyMD, но при запуске выдает куча ошибок, хотелось бы понять как решить проблему, и сильно ли она влияет на конечную сборку в exe файл?
Пробовал Clock.max_iteration но не помогало.
С kivy пока мало знаком.

[image: Ошибки]
Основной код .ру

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import WindowBase

Window.size = (710, 500)

Window.resizable = (False, False)


class ContainerBX(BoxLayout):
    Stopdot = False
    all_simbols = []
    int_simbols = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ]
    plus_AndOther = ["+", "-", "*"]
    plus_AndOtherStop = False

    def add_numbers(self, numbers, x=1):


        self.all_simbols.append(numbers)


        if ( (self.plus_AndOtherStop != True) or (self.all_simbols[-1] not in self.plus_AndOther) ):
            self.plus_AndOtherStop = False
            if ( (self.all_simbols[-1] != ".") or (self.Stopdot == False) ):
                if (((len(self.display.text)) < 20 and self.display.text != "Error")):
                    self.display.text += str(numbers)
                    print(self.all_simbols)
                else:
                    self.display.text = "Error"
            if self.all_simbols[-1] not in self.int_simbols:
                if (self.all_simbols[-1] == "."):
                    self.Stopdot = True
                else:
                    self.Stopdot = False
            if self.all_simbols[-1] not in self.int_simbols:
                if (self.all_simbols[-1] in self.plus_AndOther):
                    self.plus_AndOtherStop = True
                else:
                    self.plus_AndOtherStop = False
        print(self.all_simbols)



    def main_operation(self, calculation, x):

        try:
            self.display.text = str(round((eval(calculation)), 2))
        except Exception:
            if (x == 1):
                self.display.text = " "
            else:
                self.display.text = "Error"


class CalculatorApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepPurple"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "400"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"



        return ContainerBX()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CalculatorApp().run()
```

Код .kv

```
<ContainerBX>:

    id: calculator
    display: entry
    orientation: 'vertical'

    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: "calculator_1"
                FloatLayout
                    MDLabel:
                        theme_text_color: "Secondary"
                        multiline: False
                        id: entry
                        text:
                        pos_hint: {"x":0.1,"y":0.5,"top":1,"bottom":1,"left":0.5,"right":0.95}
                        font_size: 60
                        size_hint: 1, .60
                        text_size: (350, 180)
                        halign: "right"


                GridLayout:
                    padding: 25,25,25,25
                    spacing:4
                    cols: 4
                    size_hint: 1, .6
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text:"7"
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"8"
                        id: button_8
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"9"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"*"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"4"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"5"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"6"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"-"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"1"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:

                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"2"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:

                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"3"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"+"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"C"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.main_operation(self.text, x = 1)
                            calculator.add_numbers(" ",x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"0"
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"."
                        on_release:
                            calculator.add_numbers(self.text, x = 0)
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        size_hint: 1,1
                        text:"="
                        on_release:
                            calculator.main_operation(entry.text, x = 0)


            Screen:
                name: "calculator_2"
                FloatLayout
                    MDLabel:
                        theme_text_color: "Secondary"

                        text: "Hi"


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            FloatLayout:

                MDRaisedButton:
                    pos_hint: {"x":1,"y":1,"top":.95,"bottom":1,"left":.9,"right":.9}
                    size_hint: .80,.08
                    font_size: 30
                    text:"1"
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current = "calculator_1"

                MDRaisedButton:
                    pos_hint: {"x":.1,"y":.1,"top":.82,"bottom":.1,"left":.3,"right":.9}
                    size_hint: .80,.08
                    font_size: 30
                    text:"2"
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current = "calculator_2"
```